# Left-biased and Right-biased?

Tags: scala

I read an article about [partial unificaton](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/partial-unification.html) and the author mentioned about **Left-biased and Right-biased** datatypes.
Could someone please explain it to me, what are **Left-biased and Right-biased** datatypes?
What it has to do with **Function1**?
Is `Either` Left-biased or Right-biased?

Comment: See the top of this gist for an example of new right biased Either: https://gist.github.com/izmailoff/aa8663de3b9bd787391b3c0adf1d1146

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll give a bit broader answer, hope you don't mind.

ADTs, or Algebraic Data Types, can be divided into **sum types** and **product types**. This is not specific to Scala, but a general functional programming concept.

Product types are such that include several underlying types with an implicit boolean **and** between them. For example, a Student is a FirstName *and* LastName *and* Age *and* CoursesEnrolled. Sum types on the other hand have an implicit **or** between them. For example, a Car is a Porsche *or* Audi *or* Ferrari.

In Scala, product types are most commonly modelled as case classes, and sum types are modelled as hierarchies where base trait or abstract class gets inherited by all the possible instances (often case classes). Given our previous examples, Student would be a

```
case class Student(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int, classesEnrolled: Vector[Course])
```

and Car would be a

```
sealed trait Car
trait Porsche extends Car
trait Audi extends Car
trait Ferrari extends Car
```

In case of sum types, there are a lot of small design choices whether to e.g. use a trait or an abstract class for the base, whether to use a trait or a case class for the instances, etc. I'm not going to go into that now. Also, small FYI: in FP-oriented Scala libraries such as scalaz, cats, shapeless etc. there are other handy representations for product and sum types.

Sum types can have two or more different values; our Car example had three. Often we only need two - Option, Either, Future, Try are only some examples of sum types from vanilla Scala which only have two possible values. In these cases, we can use `map` and `flatMap` to apply a function to the value in case of a "happy scenario" (Some for Option, Right for Either etc) and leave it unchanged otherwise (in case of None, Left etc).

But, this is only possible if the sum type in question is **right biased**. Right biased means that functions such as `map` and `flatMap` apply only to the "right side" or "happy side" and leave the other one untouched. Up until Scala 2.12, Either was unbiased, which meant that you couldn't just take an Either of something and map it. It would be unclear whether the mapping function should be applied to the Right or Left. You would need to use the "right projection" in order to make it right-biased and therefore mappable and flatmappable (that also means that it can be used in for comprehensions etc. so it's really handy).

But as I said, with Scala 2.12. it became right-biased, which is IMHO a better design choice, and fits perfectly with other similar sum types from other libraries. For example, it's very easy now to go from Either to \/ (scalaz dicjuntion) now that there is no bias mismatch. They are completely isomorphic.

I'm not sure what you mean by "what it has to do with `Function1`". It's a function of one parameter. It's what you use to `map` and `flatMap` the two-value data types from previous examples (Option, Either etc).

Comment: `Function1` takes two type parameters (the input and the output). When `-Ypartial-unification` is enabled the compiler will assume that `Function1` is right-biased. Read more [here](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/7a81a395c461fd3a09a6941d4cd040f2).

Comment: @jwvh Yeah, I meant one actual argument (which is first type; second type is for return value). I will read about its right bias though, thanks.